# Compile time error when using "new double"

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

I've created a hash table and I'm trying to use enumeration in order to print out the keys as well as the values. When I try to compile the code, I keep getting a compile time error saying i need to put a '[' in new double's i've put into the hashtable.

Before compile: 
toys.put("Race Car", new double (29.99));

Compile time error says I need to place it like this:

toys.put("Race Car", new double [29.99]);

what am i doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Hashtable toys = new Hashtable();
  Enumeration toyName;
  String getToyName;
  double priceOfToy;
  toys.put("Race Car", new double(29.99));
  toys.put("Toy Bear", new double(15.99));
  toys.put("Action Figure", new double(9.99));
  //Show prices of each toy
  toyName = toys.keys();
  //Uses hasMoreElements method from enumeration to check what is in the hashtable
  while (toyName.hasMoreElements())  {
    //uses nextElement method from enumeration interface to 
    getToyName = (String) toyName.nextElement();
    System.out.println(getToyName +  "is now priced at " + toys.get(getToyName));
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you still using Java 1.4?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to java, where do I check that?

Comment: You can't `new` a primitive type. However, because of auto-boxing (since 1.5), just use: `toys.put("Minigun", 999.99)`. Also, please include the *exact* copy-paste error message in questions.

Comment: I formated it the way you said @pst and this is what i got
Warnings from last compilation:
Note:/Applications/../.. Uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Comment: @pst i already did and it didn't even come close to helping me. thanks for being supportive, as always.

Comment: Bullying a newb at java, you must be really cool.

Comment: Why, yes. Helping you help yourself is "bullying". Don't take it personally, but there is *nothing special about you when it comes to computer programming*. Accept the errors; research based on the problem at hand; learn from existing resources.

Comment: Note to self, be dick to someone who doesn't really know how to help themself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map only accepts Objects, not primitives, double is a primitive and Double is an Object.
and also consider using generic types for your collections:

```
Hashtable<String, Double> toys = new Hashtable<String, Double>();     
     toys.put("Race Car", new Double(29.99));
      toys.put("Toy Bear", new Double(15.99));
      toys.put("Action Figure", new Double(9.99));}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java collections cannot hold primitive types. You need to change

```
toys.put("Race Car", new double(29.99))
```

to

```
toys.put("Race Car", new Double(29.99))
```

which uses the `Double` wrapper type.

You can also use autoboxing with simply

```
toys.put("Race Car", 29.99)
```

Note that I haven't tested this last one to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

`double` is primitive type. Use wrapper class `Double` instead. Collections cannot hold values of primitive types because of the limitation of generics, you have to use wrappers.

Compiler shows this warning because it supposes that you wanted to instantiate an array, which can be done using `new double [22]`.

Also, if you use Java 1.5 or later, you can just use primitive values in place of wrapper values, they will automatically converted to a wrapped object.

Answer (score 0):

The class that wraps a `double`  is `Double` (capitalization is important).

So:

```
toys.put("Race Car", new Double(29.99));
```

Alternatively, since Java 5, autoboxing (converting a double to Double automatically) is suuported, so

```
 toys.put("Race Car", 29.99d));
```

is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the `Double` class

```
toys.put("Race Car", new Double(29.99));
toys.put("Toy Bear", new Double(15.99));
toys.put("Action Figure", new Double(9.99));
```

or the java primitive `double`

```
toys.put("Race Car", 29.99);   // Java 1.5 or higher, makes use of inboxing
toys.put("Toy Bear", 15.99);
toys.put("Action Figure", 9.99);
```

Java primitives are not classes and don't have constructors.